# Primefaces datatable pagination issue in single form

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I am using primefaces datatable pagination together with other controls (submit button) in a single form. Issue is that when I include other controls (submit button) in the form that contains datatable, the pagination stops working. If I exclude other controls from this form, pagination works fine.

Here is my xhtml:

```
<table id="content_tbl">
    <h:form>
    <tr>
        <td id="content_tbl_row_first_menu">
            <h:commandButton action="#{roleBean.navigateToAdd}" alt="Add" image="../css/images/20x20/Plus.png"
                rendered="#{policyBean.userAllowedToAddRole}" title="Add" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td id="content_tbl_row_third_list">

            <p:dataTable id="dtbl_role" var="role" value="#{roleBean.roles}" dynamic="true"
                paginator="true" rows="10"  
                    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
                    rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">

                <f:facet name="header">  
                    Roles  
                </f:facet>

                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Role" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{role.name}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
            <p:growl id="messages" />               
        </td>
    </tr>       
    </h:form>
</table>
```

Here is my bean:

```
public class RoleBackingBean extends Role implements Serializable{

/**
 * Navigate to add page
 * @return
 */
public String navigateToAdd() {

    return "navigate_to_add";
}

public List<Role> getRoles() {

    return new RoleHomeImpl().getRoleList();
}
```

}

Kindly let me know if further code is needed. Any help would be appreciated.

Umar

Comment: Is your managed bean `@ViewScoped` or has a wider scope?

Comment: I am using faces-config for bean scoping. It is of request scope.

Comment: It looks like you're using JSF 1.2, if this is the case, then you should save/load the list to/from session after getting the data. If you're using JSF 2.x, then 1: remove the configuration from the `faces-config.xml` and add `@ManagedBean` and `@ViewScoped` annotations to your `RoleBackingBean` class from `javax.faces.annotation` package, or 2: change the bean from request scope to view scope.

Comment: I have done what you told me but it still does not work. The error I get on pressing 'next page' is:                                                                        <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response><error><error-name>class java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException</error-name><error-message><![CDATA[String index out of range: -1]]></error-message></error></partial-response>

Comment: My primefaces version is 3.3.1 so JSF 2.X

Comment: OK, problem solved. It seems I cannot use html tags (table, tr, td). I used panelGrid instead and it solved the issue. Luiggi, thanks for the help